# After Google EndPoint 2.0 migration: 404 and spi instead of api

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

I migrated my Android app and backend from Google Cloud EndPoints 1.0 to 2.0. The Endpoint calls from the Android app are now failing with 404.

I did change the web.xml configuration to point to /_ah/api instead of /_ah/spi. However the log still reports calls to be made to spi instead of api.

When I use the API explorer, the web UI reports calls being made to /_ah/api but the appengine log reports them as being made to /_ah/spi. Both report 404 error.

I've spent a few hours reading everything on the web and trying. No luck. A while back I successfully migrated another app and backend. I compared the two and can't see what's different.

**Project build.gradle:**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "central.maven.org"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-client'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.playposse.peertopeeroxygen.android"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 23
        versionName "23.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    endpointsServer project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'endpoints')

    // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
    // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
    // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
    androidTestImplementation group: 'com.restfb', name: 'restfb', version: '1.43.0'

    // Needed to resolve  conflict
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:android-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:+'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.23.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:1.6.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Backend build.gradle:**

```
// If you would like more information on the gradle-appengine-plugin please refer to the github page
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.3'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.0.9'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.17'
    implementation group: 'com.restfb', name: 'restfb', version: '1.43.0'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.23.0'
}

// V2: Define deployment configuration using the new App Engine plugin
// with the appengine closure
appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
    deploy {   // deploy configuration

        // The following is used for acceptance tests and
        // is not required for a migration.
        project = findProperty("appengine.deploy.project")
        version = findProperty("appengine.deploy.version")
        def promoteProp = findProperty("appengine.deploy.promote")
        if (promoteProp != null) {
            promote = new Boolean(promoteProp)
        }
    }
}
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>peertopeeroxygen</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.playposse.peertopeeroxygen.backend.PeerToPeerOxygenEndPoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.playposse.peertopeeroxygen.backend.util.ObjectifyRegistrationServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: A fix is being rolled out. If you use the versioned URL (version-dot-project.appspot.com), you may be able to access it correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any references to a bug report? By the way, my other v2 endpoint project works completely fine.

Comment: Using 2-dot-peertopeeroxygen.appspot.com, I was able to hit my end point. When you say a fix is being rolled out, are the instances restarting right now and should work within hours? Or is there a dev process involved that might takes weeks?

Comment: It should roll out by the end of the week, after which you need to try switching the default version again. I'll update this when it's ready for you.

Comment: This seems to be the public issue for tracking: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76031966

Comment: This should now be fixed. Please attempt to switch the default version back to the migrated version and report of there are errors.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I re-deployed the endpoint service. It's still the same problem. The app and API explorer fail with 404. The API explorer shows "api" in the URL, yet the appengine log record shows "spi."

Comment: Someone from Google connected with me via hangout chat. Re-deploying to another app version and waiting longer did the trick. It's all working again now.